# Sea Searpent during invasion of Fire Giant in Blood Rage

Tags: blood-rage

John controls Sea Serpent in the fiord. Alice decides to invade an adjacent province with Fire Giant. Does the Sea Serpent get destroyed?

Fire Giant is supposed to destroy everything except for monsters. Sea Serpent is supposed to be treated as a ship for all intents and purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sea serpent counts as a ship but it is a Monster upgrade. It goes in the monster upgrade slot. Fire Giants don't destroy other monsters. The Fire giant won't destroy anything that goes in the monster upgrade slot.